# Magento2 select by default one radio button in system configuration

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, system.xml, system-config

In my custom module **system.xml** I added

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="Customodule" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
        <label>Settings</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="ConnSettings" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Connection Settings</label>
        <tab>Customodule</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Customodule::config</resource>
        <group id="first" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">

<field id="accessLevel" translate="label" type="radios" sortOrder="6" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Access Level</label>
    <source_model>Vendor\CustomModule\Model\Source\AccessLevel</source_model>
</field>
```

Model file is as

```
class AccessLevel implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        return  [
                    [
                        'value' => 'test', 
                        'label' => __('Testing')
                    ], 
                    [
                        'value' => 'production', 
                        'label' => __('Production')
                    ],
                ];
    }

}
```

I want to select **Test** option by default.

What should I do please reply me!!!

Comment: Please add your group tag from system.xml in your question, so I will add full code with group id

Comment: group tag id is "first"

Comment: can you please add full code ?

Comment: Please add your config.xml and system.xml code

Comment: question edited

Comment: Check my updated ans

Comment: check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Comment: @iqbalmalik Please accept answer, so it will helpful for other developers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in your config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <ConnSettings>
            <first>
                <accessLevel>test</accessLevel>
            </first>
        </ConnSettings>
    </default>
</config>
```

Remove value from `core_config_data` table and upgrade and deploy.

Answer (score 4):

Please add following code in your `etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
   <default>
       <ConnSettings>
            <first>
                <accessLevel>test</accessLevel>
            </first>
       </ConnSettings>
   </default>
</config>
```

Comment: i tried this but nothing happened

Comment: please add your full system.xml code in your question.

Comment: @iqbalmalik is this working for you ?